# Not able to create instance for WinSCP Session class

Tags: c#-4.0, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am using WinSCP to download and upload files in C# program. My code look like this

```
    public Session OpenSftpSession ()
    {
       SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions ();
       sessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Sftp;
       sessionOptions.HostName = this.hostName_;
       sessionOptions.UserName = this.userName_;
       sessionOptions.Password = this.password_;
       sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = this.sshHostKeyFingerprint_;

       Session session = null;
       try
       {
           session = new Session ();
           session.Open (sessionOptions);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return null;
       }

       return session;
    }
```

When program execute line

```
    session = new Session ();
```

it terminates. I don't even get any exception it just terminates.

Thanks,
Darshan.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even when following zmx's sample. It just simply refused to instantiate the Session object. I ended up doing the following (from the [instructions on the WinSCP.net site](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs)):

1. Downloading version 5.2.4 beta (both the .NET assembly and the portable executable).
2. Adding a reference to the **WinSCPnet.dll** (note the name).
3. Placing **WinSCP.exe** in the root folder of the project.
4. Setting it's properties (WinSCP.exe) with a "Build Action" of "**None**", and a "Copy to Ouput Directory" of "**Copy if newer**".

The DLL and the EXE in combination make it work as expected. Just using the DLL doesn't work as it simply provides a wrapper around the EXE. Additionally, older versions of the WinSCP assembly have the name WinSCP.dll which conflicts with the name of the EXE; so having both the DLL and the EXE in the bin folder doesn't work.

Comment: Were OP's problems related to `winscp.exe`, problem would appear only after calling `Session.Open`. The `Session` constructor does not use `winscp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

simply paste the WinScp.exe and winScp.dll in your application folder, as i have done:

```
D:\Orient Service\FinpayTransferservice-webservice\bin\x86\Debug
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying loading your `sessionOptions` like the sample on the [WinSCP website](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp).

For example your code would look something like:

```
 public Session OpenSftpSession ()
{
   SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
   { 
       Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Sftp;
       HostName = this.hostName_;
       UserName = this.userName_;
       Password = this.password_;
       SshHostKeyFingerprint = this.sshHostKeyFingerprint_;
   }

   Session session = null;
   try
   {
       session = new Session ();
       session.Open(sessionOptions);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return null;
   }

   return session;
}
```